# I am getting frequently low disk space message

Tags: 12.04

I am frequently getting low disk space error and attached screen displayed.

Let me know what to do.

Comment: then add some disk space :) and use anything like baobob to see whats clogging your PC

Comment: hi utkarsha.. txns for your comment. But let me clarify that I am very new to ubuntu and just installed it 2 days back along with windows-xp duel os mode. So I need more precise answer which can be understand by me. txns again

Comment: first run `sudo apt-get clean` and tell me if enough space is cleaned. if not, tell me. we both will take some more steps to clean unnecessary data. feel free to ask :)

Comment: txns utkarsha. some of space is created.

Comment: Obviously you are running low on disk space. What to do? It depends on whether you would like to find what is using so much space on disk. Or whether you just want to get rid of that message and leave things as is. Could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 11):

To delete downloaded packages (.deb) already installed (and no longer needed)

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

To remove all stored archives in your cache for packages that can not be downloaded anymore (thus packages that are no longer in the repository or that have a newer version in the repository).

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

To remove unnecessary packages (After uninstalling an app there could be packages you don't need anymore)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To delete old kernel versions

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-X.X.XX-XX-generic
```

If you don't know which kernel version to remove

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
```

Comment: i hope this will help

Answer (score 10):

You can open a terminal and run

```
df -h
```

This will show you how much space is left. The `-h` flag is to have *human* readable output.

If you have too little space there are two things you can do to find out what you could delete.

First,

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu
cd / 
ncdu
```

Ncdu has options to go through your files and see which folders are too large and which you can delete. Don't delete system files, though unless you know what you are doing. Focus on the home folder.

Second, you can find out whether you have duplicate files. If so you could spare some space here. For that purpose you can install fdupes,

```
sudo apt-get install fdupes
cd $HOME
fdupes -r . # use -d to get a delete promt
```