# Low disk space on ubuntu

Tags: disk-usage

I have recently dual booted my pc with ubuntu and windows and total space available for lonux was 39GB . It worked fine for 4-5 days but suddenly showing low dsk space with only 2.1GB left even without installing anything.
I have tried cleaning up cache ,old kernels and ended up in freeing only 0.6 GB space.
How to clean up this remaining space?

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424549/i-am-getting-frequently-low-disk-space-message), help?

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking about server? desktop? or provided release details...

Comment: For what it's worth, on my "average" desktop, my `/usr` and `/var` combined is about 15 GB, so maybe using up 35 GB is odd.  I also have a swapfile at `/swapfile` (swap partition if you're using an older version of Ubuntu) that is 2 GB.  How big is your swapfile?  If you don't have a program that is taking up disk space over time (i.e., `ncdu` should help find that), you might be fine to ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

U can use ncdu to find out which folders/files are biggest

`sudo apt-get install ncdu`

`sudo ncdu`

[image]